# Counting in R and preserving the order of occurence

Tags: r, aggregate

Suppose I have generated a vector using the following statement:

```
x1 <- rep(4:1, sample(1:100,4))
```

Now, when I try to count the number of occurrences using the following commands

```
count(x1)
  x freq
1 1   40
2 2   57
3 3    3
4 4   46
```

or

```
as.data.frame(table(x1))
  x1 Freq
1  1   40
2  2   57
3  3    3
4  4   46
```

In both cases, the order of occurrence is not preserved. I want to preserve the order of occurrence, i.e. the output should be like this

```
  x1 Freq
1  4   46
2  3    3
3  2   57
4  1   40
```

What is the cleanest way to do this? Also, is there a way to coerce a particular order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to convert your variable to `factor` and specify the desired order with the `levels` argument. From `?table`: "table uses the cross-classifying factors to build a contingency table of the counts at each combination of factor levels"; "It is best to supply factors rather than rely on coercion.". So by converting to factor yourself, you are in charge over the coercion and the order set by `levels`.

```
x1 <- rep(factor(4:1, levels = 4:1), sample(1:100,4))

table(x1)
# x1
#  4  3  2  1 
#  90 72 11 16
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `rle` function

```
rle(x1)
## Run Length Encoding
##   lengths: int [1:4] 12 2 23 52
##   values : int [1:4] 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can order the table like this:

```
set.seed(42)
x1 <- rep(4:1, sample(1:100,4))

table(x1)[order(unique(x1))]
# x1
#  4  3  2  1 
# 92 93 29 81
```